# Prolog If statement fact

Tags: prolog

I want to state a unique fact in my Prolog data base to change the outcome of my if statement.

My code is as follows:

```
suspect(Killer, mrBoddy) :-
    affair(mrBoddy, Y),
    married(X,Y),
    write('Killer= '),
    write(X), nl;
    greedy(X),
    write('Killer= '),
    write(X), nl.
```

The output is

```
?- suspect(Killer, mrBoddy).                                      
Killer= profPlum

true ? ;
Killer= colMustard

yes
```

My Facts

```
affair(mrBoddy, msGreen).
affair(mrBoddy,missScarlet).
married(profPlum, msGreen).

rich(mrBoddy).
greedy(colMustard).
motive_to_kill_affair(profPlum).
motive_to_kill_greed(colMustard).
```

I want to add a fact that will change the output to only one "Killer". Doesn't matter who it is. How could I achieve this?

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve]?

Comment: I believe I have edited it enough to provide the Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example now.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by `I want to add a fact that will change the ouput to only one "Killer"`?

Comment: Of course, right now when I run 
?- suspect(Killer, mrBoddy).
Killer = suspect_name_1
Killer = suspect_name_2

I want to add a fact that will change the output to
?-suspect(Killer,mrBoddy) 
Killer = unique_suspect.

Comment: I got that. I don't know what you mean by that.

Comment: Firstly, don't use `write` to output your results. It's fine for debugging, but not intended for getting results of a query. You should have an additional variable to `suspect` that would hold a valid solution. Also, your logic isn't clear. What defines a suspect? Why is `mrBoddy` a hard-coded argument in your logic? If you write your predicate in such a way that it defines exactly what makes `X` a suspect (and make `X` an argument to your predicate), it should get you there. You're currently writing out various intermediate matches to facts, which is not the end result.